# Как сделать адаптивный хедер?

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка, flexbox

Так сейчас хедер у меня выглядит у меня при уменьшении экрана?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
}

body{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #42c1b0;
}

html{
    font-size: 100%;
}


.meta{
    height: auto;
}

.main{
    background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 80px;
    position: relative;
     padding: 0 180px 0 150px;
}

.header{
    height: 80px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    width: 1280px;
    padding: 0 180px 0 150px;
}


.logo h1{
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #3cc3b5;
}

.korzina {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.korzina img, .korzina h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.korzina h2{
    color: #a1a1a1;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Lobster';
    font-weight: 300;
    position: relative;
    left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
}




/*Search form*/
.search img{
    position: relative;
    top: 4px;
}

.search-form {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.search-form-input {

  width: 435px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 38px 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.search-form-btn {
  /* Позиционирование относительно <form> */
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px; /* 2px - размер border'а поля формы */
  top: 2px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;

  /* Просто тюнинг внешнего вида */
  color: #666;
  font-weight: bold;      
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*and search form*/
```

```html
<div class="main">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo">
            <h1>Aditii</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="search">
            <form action="#" class="search-form">
                  <input type="search" class="search-form-input" placeholder="" />
                    <button type="submit" class="search-form-btn">
                    <!-- Сюда можно запихнуть любую картинку на свой вкус -->
                       <img src="img/Search%201.png" alt="">
                    </button>
            </form>
            </div>
            <div class="korzina">
          <img src="img/Korzinka.png" alt=""> 
           <h2>$300</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Вот так бы я хотел сделать, чтобы при уменьшении экрана логотип смещался в левый конец сайта а форма поиска уменьшалась при уменьшении экрана и корзинка смещалась влево вместе с уменьшением формы поиска

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Варианты решения:

1. Вы можете оформить хедер flexbox'ом и задать внутри каждого блока процентную величину.
2. Размеры каждому элементу можно указать относительно размера базового размера шрифта `rem` или относительно родителя `em`. Еще можно использовать размеры относительно размера вьюпорта:

   - vw – 1% ширины окна
   - vh – 1% высоты окна
   - vmin – наименьшее из (vw,
     vh), в IE9 обозначается vm
   - vmax – наибольшее из (vw, vh)
3. Использовать `media-queries` которые будут срабатывать при определенных условиях. При нужном размере экрана будут применены правила написанные в них. (автор другого ответа дал пример)
4. Использовать JS для правильного отображения содержимого. Например ивент `.resize()` не редко применяется для некоторых задач.

Для вашей задачи отлично подойдут `media-queries`. Например для изменения размера логотипа и поля поиска при размере вьюпорта меньше 900px по ширине можно сделать так:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .logo h1 {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    .search-form-input {
        width: 275px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам помогут media-queries. Медиа-запросы срабатывают, когда выполняется заданное в них условие. К примеру, самое простое - изменим размер шрифта, если ширина экрана меньше 993px:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 993px) {
    body {
        font-size: 15px
    }    
}
```

Удачи.